# StackNavigator have no Header in a TabRouter

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I made myself a custom TabBar with gradient background and stuff with TabRouter (because you can't make one with TabNavigator right?). But one of my tab is a StackNavigator and it doesn't display the navBar on top of the screen. Do I need to manually add it the CustomTabView?

Shouldn't the ActiveScreen handle the navBar if it's a StackNavigator?

```
const Tabs = TabRouter(
  {
    Main: {
      // My StackNavigator which should have a navBar on top...
      screen: StackNavigator({
        Dashboard: {
          screen: Dashboard,
          title: 'Dashboard',
        },
        Wallet: { screen: Wallet },
        Deck: { screen: Deck },
        EnterpriseProfile: { screen: EnterpriseProfile },
      }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    backBehavior: 'none',
  },
);

const CustomTabView = ({ router, navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
  const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForState(navigation.state);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0 }}>
      <ActiveScreen
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          ...navigation,
          state: routes[index],
        })}
      />

     // My Custom TabBar because I don't want the default one from TabNavigator
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={route.routeName} onPress={() => navigation.dispatch({ type: 'Navigation/BACK' })}
          >
            <TabItem />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const TabBar = createNavigationContainer(createNavigator(Tabs)(CustomTabView));

export default TabBar;
```